# How to rename files during copying for vfat

Tags: regex, linux, file, shell

How can files be renamed during copying on the linux shell converting different characters into other different characters ?

I know that you can use the pax tool for doing this.

Example: 
`pax -rw -s '/?:/_/g/ INPUTDIR OUTPUTDIR`

I have the following directory structure

```
 - source
   +- documentation?
      +- file:examples
```

But I would like to convert `:` to `CL` **and** `?` to `QM`

This does not work:
 `pax -rw -s '/?/QM/g/ -s '/:/CL/g/  INPUTDIR OUTPUTDIR`

and this not either: 
 `pax -w -s '/?/QM/g/ INPUTDIR | pax -r -s '/:/CL/g/ OUTPUTDIR`

Comment: _maybe_  you need to escape `?` as _`\?`_

Comment: Sorry but that does not help - after trying it.

Comment: Besides the missing backslash: the man pax says multiple -s are possible but the first one succeeding stops further substitution - so it cannot be done - see http://linux.die.net/man/1/pax

Comment: I did something similar, when symlinks are not used in the INPUTDIR: recreate the directory structure under some TEMPDIR; symlink all files from INPUTDIR into TEMPDIR hierarchy; patch the file names in the TEMPDIR; then `tar` with dereference / un-`tar` the TEMPDIR to OUTPUTDIR.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a shell command of a directory listing and make single pax commands replacing the entire name, using `\?`.

Comment: Okay - but my idea was to pipe multiple pax commands to avoid creating an additional script.

Comment: The -s seems to be a rename of the input file to the output file - right? So a pipe will not do, and repeating the pax also not. _I think_. Probably a smart linuxer may do it in a shell script maybe using backticks or whatever.

Comment: If I use the piped pax command  `pax -w -s '/?/QM/g' source/ | pax -s '/:/CL/g`  the output is correct as needed. **But** it is only printed on stdout.

Comment: Does not pax need an existing input file, creating a new output file? A pipe is unnamed. Consecutive calling is not possible due to missing input by that name. I would have thought it logically impossible, but I do not know pax. You might copy first to a non-vfat **ramdisk** with one -s and then to the final vfat with the second -s. But that would be even uglier.